# Removing item from redux-stored list and redirect back to list - delay props evaluating?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having view with list of Steps. Each step can be "viewed" and "removed" from within the "view" screen. 
My `StepDetails` component binds to redux store by fetching corresponding step from `steps` part of store with simple `steps.find(...)`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let stepId = ownProps.params.stepId;
  let step = state.steps.find(s => s.id === stepId);
  return {step};
};
```

Now when (from within "details") I hit "Delete step" I want this step to be removed from store and I want to navigate to list view.

There is redux action invoked on delete that returns new steps list without this one removed and redirect is called afterwards:

```
const deleteStep = (stepId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return stepsApi.deleteStep(stepId).then(steps => {
      dispatch(action(STEPS_LIST_CHANGED, {steps}));
      // react-router-redux action to redirect
      dispatch(redirectToList());
    })
  }
};
```

This is fine and does what I want, with one drawback: when `STEPS_LIST_CHANGED` action is called and step gets removed from the list, my component's `mapStateToProps` gets called before this redirect. Result is that `mapStateToProps` cannot obviously find this step anymore and my component gives me errors that step is undefined etc.

What I can do is to check if step provided to component is defined, and if not render nothing etc. But it's kind of defensive programming flavor I don't really like, as I don't want my component to know what to do if it gets wrong data.

I can also swap actions dispatch order: redirect first and then alter state, but then it doesn't feel right too (logically you first want to delete and then redirect).

How do you handle such cases?

**EDIT:**
What I ended up with was to put this null/undefined-check into container component (one that does redux wiring). With that approach I don't clutter my presentational components with unnecessary logic. It also can be abstracted out to higher order component (or ES7 decorator probably) to render `null` or `<div></div>` when some required props are not present.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

- Delegating the list changed to the redirect? For example:

  ```
  dispatch(redirectToList(action(STEPS_LIST_CHANGED, {steps})));
  ```
- Handling the null step component to ignore rendering:

  ```
  shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
      return this.state.steps != null;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your return statement into an array

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let stepId = ownProps.params.stepId;
  let step = state.steps.find(s => s.id === stepId);
  return step ? [{step}] : []
};
```

This way on your component you can do a `step.map()` and render it.

Comment: It feels too hacky to me, this one-element array is completely artificial there, doesn't provide much value but brings noise to intentions readability

Comment: @MichalOstruszka actually you might spot this on many API-s and the approach to it is still functional while your function remains pure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you want an **atomic action that will do both the deletion and redirect**. This is not possible because the Redux store and URL are [two separate states](http://jamesknelson.com/5-types-react-application-state/) that cannot be updated in one run.

As a result, the user can see for a brief moment either:

- an empty entity detail page before the redirect or
- the deleted entity in the list after redirect.

One way to deal with that is to use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (or [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)) and prevent component re-render after entity has vanished:

```js
const entityWasDeleted = (prevProps, nextProps) => 
  prevProps.entity !== undefined && nextProps.entity === undefined

export default React.memo(EntityDetailComponent, entityWasDeleted)
```

It's a little bit hacky, because `React.memo` should not be used like this, but the component gets unmounted in the next step so who cares.